# How to get additional fields from Google groups API

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-api-dotnet-client, google-groups-api

I would like to list all groups on my google domain that has specific "type" (team,domain, etc.)
when i use the groups.list() method using directory API i get all the groups.
does anybody knows about a way to query by fields so the returned list will be filtered?

thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by type? What is for example a "team group"?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in the Directory documentation:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-groups#get_all_domain_groups

Anyway I also added the google-admin-sdk tag as suggested at https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/support

Comment: Hi,I've took a look at it before posting the question. didn't find any way to filter by "type" field, as it's not present on the response. Do you familiar with other API that can help here? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to list all groups on my google domain that has specific "type" is  CUSTOMER.
Does anybody knows about a way to query by fields so the returned list will be filtered?

```
{
    "kind": "admin#directory#members",
    "etag": "\"t3T4wFaZo04vdXaxNQGkK1fzKz4/w4BU1oBly0ZCiFmdIX3OZdWgmsI\"",
    "members": [
        {

             "kind": "admin#directory#member",
             "etag": "\"t3T4wFaZo04vdXaxNQGkK1fzKz4/q8PZ1ZbbaQxYeAB7lQTCQIZeTbc\"",
             "id": "C035o7jwg",
             "role": "MEMBER",
             "type": "CUSTOMER"
        }
    ]
}
```